# How do I call a method from a Domain Service class

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, asp.net-membership

Once again I am in need of some assistance with regard to calling a Domain Service class method from silverlight.

This ties in somewhat to my question of yesterday which was solved. Thanks again!
For those who are interested, my question of yesterday can be found here:

[Using ASP.net membership to get aspnet_Users in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376167/using-asp-net-membership-to-get-aspnet-users-in-silverlight)

Now onto my current question.

I have the following method in Domain Service Class called MembershipData

```
 [RequiresRole("Managers")]
 public void DeleteUser(MembershipServiceUser user)
 {
     Membership.DeleteUser(user.UserName);
 }
```

- This code is from kylemc's tutorial

Now how do I call this method from within Silverlight?

I understand from yesterday's question that

```
public IEnumerable<MembershipServiceUser> GetAllUsers()
```

needs to be called by defining the query, then running the query and then calling OnGetAllUsersLoaded when the the results return.

What I am unsure of is, Do you need to call the method in this way because of its return type?

Obviously public void DeleteUser(MembershipServiceUser user) has no return type so cannot be called in this way.

It does not seem to be possible to do:

```
MembershipDataContext context = new MembershipDataContext();
MembershipServiceUser user = new MembershipServiceUser();
user.UserName = "bob";

context.DeleteUser(user);
```

But then how do I use the DeleteUser method?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Neill

Update

Thanks for the info HiTech. I still have one issue I need to solve. Perhaps I am still not doing something correctly.

I am now creating a new instance of MembershipServiceUser, lets call it msu. 
Then assigning msu.UserName and msu.Email the user details, and after that calling

```
context.MembershipServiceUsers.Remove(msu)
```

where context is my MembershipData domain service context, and I have checked that

```
context MembershipServiceUsers results
```

does have my user info. I then however get the following error

"The specified entity is not contained in this EntitySet."

I am positive the data in msu is correct, so any ideas as to why I am getting this error?
 Many thanks

Update 2

Am I on the right track with something like the following...

```
MembershipServiceUser usr = (from a in context.MembershipServiceUsers
                                     where a.UserName == "bob"
                                     select a).First();

context.MembershipServiceUsers.Remove(usr);
context.SubmitChanges(DeleteUser_completed, null);
```

Or is this way off? because in my callback DeleteUser_completed(SubmitOperation so)
so.HasError = true
while so's ChangeSet -> RemovedEntities = 1, but so's EntitiesInError's result is "enumeration yielded no results"

Once again thanks for helping steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA services works by creating a change set (literally a set of changes) and sending just those changes to the server. The methods to do CRUD are more like Entity Framework, not direct method calls.

On the client side you will call the `Remove` method on the domain context's User collection.

On the receiving side it goes through all the changes and says:

- Q. "Is this an object deletion?"
- A. Yes...
- Q. "What object type is it?"
- A. MembershipServiceUser
- Q. "Do we have a method called Delete that takes a `MembershipServiceUser` parameter?"
- A. Yes...

It then calls that method with the object from the changeset...

Comment: Please see updated question. I stuck it there because it was too long for this comment box

Comment: You have to refer to the same instance of the object that is returned from a previous query. You can't just `new` one up. Search the context for the item you want to delete and remove that specific instance instead.

Comment: Hi, Please ignore Update 2. I sorted out why it was doing it. Basically came down to me not having the correct permissions. Tx for all the assistance